# Bootstrap Carousel Active Thumbnail Styles

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails, carousel

I have this custom bootstrap carousel I am trying to work with and make the active thumbnail style change when it is active. I need to keep the thumbnail list using div vs li so that I can keep them in the responsive grid.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval:   4000
});

var clickEvent = false;
$('#myCarousel').on('click', '.thumbs a', function() {
        clickEvent = true;
        $('.thumbs .item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    if(!clickEvent) {
        var count = $('.thumbs').children().length -1;
        var current = $('.thumbs .item.active');
        current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
        if(count == id) {
            $('.thumbs .item').first().addClass('active');  
        }
    }
    clickEvent = false;
});
```

I've put together this jsfiddle to demonstrate what I'm attempting to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/vr3xyqpv/3/

The red border on the thumbnail should stay visible while it is on each slide.

It appears to be working when first viewed, but it jumps around weird and once you click a thumbnail, it stops remaining active for long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way :

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/ewx61o1k/1/

**Js** :

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval:   4000
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(){
   var index = $('.carousel-inner .item.active').index();
   $('.thumbs .item[data-slide-to="'+index+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```